# Пропуск экранированных символов строки Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл, содержащий строки такого вида: `"ключ" "значение"`.

Мне нужно было их разделить, я сделал это с помощью такой регулярки `"\\"[^\\"]*\\""`

В ходе парсинга выяснил, что есть значения наподобие `"Нажмите кнопку \\"Ок\\" чтобы продолжить"`
Здесь шаблон ломается.

Пробовал изменить шаблон так `"\\"[^\\"]*[^\\\\\\\"]\\""`, но не помогло.

Comment: `ключ значение` через пробел? В ключе пробелов нет? Тогда просто `string.Split`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такую регулярку: `^(".*?")\s(".*?")$`

[проверить](https://regex101.com/r/EyGKzY/1)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот (берите значения захваченных групп):

```
^("[\s\S]*?") ("[\s\S]*?")$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5auue